# populate table with headers using foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, api

I am trying to populate table with headers like [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caT5I.png) .
And array returns [this type of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8yCn.png).

I tried this but not works.

```
@foreach ($players['headers'] as $row_header)
   <tr>
     @foreach ($players['values'] as $values)
        <th scope="row" class="col-3">{{ $row_header }}</th>
        <th class="col-3">{{ $values['values'][0] }}</th>
        <td class="col-3">{{ $values['values'][1] }}</td>
     @endforeach
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what error or inaccurate outcome you're currently seeing, it's hard to give you a definitive answer. My suggestion based on the images you provided would be to try something like this:

```
@foreach ($players['headers'] as $key => $row_header)
   <tr>
     <th scope="row" class="col-3">{{ $row_header }}</th>
     @foreach ($players['values'] as $values)
       <td class="col-3">{{ $values['values'][$key] }}</td>
     @endforeach
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

You don't need to output the $row_header foreach iteration of $players['values'], you only need to output it once.

Your setup doesn't take into account which iteration of the foreach you're on, so you're always outputting "matches" and "innings" even when you want to be outputting other values.